# What to consider for determining something as a security flaw?

Tags: xss, vulnerability, injection, iframe

Recently, I found an iframe injection vulnerability on a website. This website allows users to create projects and name them. So I successfully injected an iframe on the naming function that can redirect me to a malicious website. But I don't know if the injection is visible to other users or to the administrators, so I don't know if this is a vulnerability.

Comment: It would seem as though you need to figure out if someone else can view that frame.

Comment: It will redirect me to another website when it loads the project's name. But I'm not sure other users can see it also because the each project is private. But I think the administrators might be able to see it, I'm not too sure.

Comment: Ok, so it ***is*** a successful injection. That's enough to raise an issue with the site.